# android connection to http refused

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to send some data to a localhost server in other computer but i couldn't do it. I'm using mac, my firewall is disabled by default. and i used the other computer's ip address, we're in the same network. I did put in the permissions required.

This is the logcat message

```
09-22 08:06:46.343: D/OpenGLRenderer(1108): Enabling debug mode 0
09-22 08:07:37.943: W/EGL_genymotion(1108): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-22 08:07:41.443: W/EGL_genymotion(1108): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-22 08:08:01.379: D/InputStream(1108): Connection to http://172.22.111.225:8080 refused
```

This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView tvIsConnected;
 EditText etName;
 EditText etCountry;
 EditText etTwitter;
 Button btnPost;

Person person;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get reference to the views
    tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCountry);
    etTwitter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTwitter);
    btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);

    // check if you are connected or not
    if(isConnected()){
        tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
    }
    else{
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
    }

    // add click listener to Button "POST"
    btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public static String POST(String url, Person person){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phonenumber",person.getName()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("peoplenumber",person.getCountry()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remark",person.getTwitter()));

    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));



        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}

public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;    
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnPost:
            if(!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
            new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://172.22.111.225:8080/OrderServer/orderServer");
        break;
    }

}
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        person = new Person();
        person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
        person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());
        person.setTwitter(etTwitter.getText().toString());

        return POST(urls[0],person);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}

private boolean validate(){
    if(etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if(etCountry.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if(etTwitter.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else
        return true;    
}
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

}

Comment: Are you able to connect to the computer from another source? As it seems the target is not accepting a connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

give that permission in the manifest file.

Comment: I did give the permission

Comment: Can you clean project and try again. There could be only 2 possibilities for this, one is no internet permission, other is that url connection might be refused because it cannot be able to access. try that url from another browser in which you tested the app.

Answer (score 0):

how about this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: yup, sorry..i just want to put it on comment, but i cant because of the reputation point